# Index pagination with links to own method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

actually i use the following code in my _user.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Delete User", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

For every user i get a link to delete him.
In my controller the delete-method calls the destroy-method:

```
def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted."
    redirect_to users_url
end
```

This all works fine.

**What i want now** is another link where a call a custom method.

How can i call a custom method?

What i already tried was to add a method with the name `test` and then i called `method: :test` but this doesn't work:

`No route matches [POST] "/users/2"`

Thanks for any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question heading is wrong, pagination means something else.

First configure your routes like

```
resources :controller_name do
    member do
     delete 'test'
    end
end
```

Your route will be set ..

```
test_controller_name DELETE /controller_name/:id/test(.:format) controller_name#test
```

Call the action from `link_to` and pass the object id .

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', test_controller_path(:id => @object.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Comment: And how did i call the action? i tried: `:controller => :users_controller, :action => :test`